# Javascript How to check if the page opened is Home Page

Tags: javascript

I am trying to check the page opened is Home Page then show the popup to register.
Register Modal will be shown by setTimeout method

```
 setTimeout(function(){ $("#modalregister").modal('show'); }, 3000);
```

The Popup should only be set on Home Page.On the other pages Register is only opened by click

```
 <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalregister" class="signup_btn">REGISTER</a>
```

How to check using window.location.href == '/'

Comment: How do you know if the current page is the "home page"?  Can you just have a different line of code on that page than on your other pages?

Comment: I wonder what's the result of `console.log(window.location.href);`

Comment: script is common on all the page.I am using Laravel

Comment: why don't you redirect if the user isn't loged in on all pages to the login/register page?

Comment: window.location.pathname will work to me. I can compare window.location.pathname = '/'